# Regex: extract word after comma before whitespace

Tags: regex, pandas

I want to extract `surname`, `first_name` and `second_name` into new columns in my df. The original string `name` separates surname from given names with a comma. I'm struggling with the first and second name, because there is sometimes whitespace after the comma. This is how it should look:

```
                      name   surname first_name second_name
0  Nancy Katherina, Dorsey    Dorsey      Nancy   Katherina
1              Alan,Harper    Harper       Alan         NaN
2       Charley Max, Sheen     Sheen    Charley         Max
3    Audrey Maria,McKinsey  McKinsey     Audrey       Maria
```

My approach so far (could only make `surname` work):

```
df['surname'] = df['name'].str.extract(r'^(.+?),', expand=True)
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Comment: You would be better to capture first middle and last names as separate groups of one match. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by `,` with optionally space after it and select values by indexing to new columns:

```
s = df['name'].str.split(',\s*')
s1 = s.str[0].str.split()

df['surname'] = s.str[-1]
df['first_name'] = s1.str[0]
df['second_name'] = s1.str[1]
print (df)
                       name   surname first_name second_name
0   Nancy Katherina, Dorsey    Dorsey      Nancy   Katherina
1               Alan,Harper    Harper       Alan         NaN
2        Charley Max, Sheen     Sheen    Charley         Max
3     Audrey Maria,McKinsey  McKinsey     Audrey       Maria
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common use for a regex.

I'm not familiar with your `panda` environment but this regex will do what you want:

```
^\s*(\w+)\s*(\w*)\s*,\s*(.*)\s*$
```

You can test it with a regex tester (there are lots online) and it will correctly cope with no second name and no space after the comma.

the * quantifier means zro or more so it will match if it's there and also if it's not.  The brackets provide the grouping to extract what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The regex pattern `'(\w+)\s*(\w+)?,\s*(\w+)'` will work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'Nancy Katherina, Dorsey'},
 {'name': 'Alan,Harper'},
 {'name': 'Charley Max, Sheen'},
 {'name': 'Audrey Maria,McKinsey'}])

df[['first_name', 'second_name', 'surname']] = df['name'].str.extract('(\w+)\s*(\w+)?,\s*(\w+)')
print(df[['name', 'surname', 'first_name', 'second_name']])

                      name   surname first_name second_name
0  Nancy Katherina, Dorsey    Dorsey      Nancy   Katherina
1              Alan,Harper    Harper       Alan         NaN
2       Charley Max, Sheen     Sheen    Charley         Max
3    Audrey Maria,McKinsey  McKinsey     Audrey       Maria
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following code, using [`df.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) function.

```
df[["first_name", "second_name", "surname"]] = df['name'].str.extract('^(\S+)(?:\s+(\S+))?,\s*(.*)$', expand=False)
print(df[['name', 'surname', 'first_name', 'second_name']])
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^(\S+)         ##Matching everything before 1st space(s) occurrences in 1st capturing group.
(?:\s+(\S+))?  ##In a non-capturing group matching spaces followed by non-spaces in 2nd capturing group, keeping this optional.
,\s*           ##Matching comma followed by 0 or more spaces occurrences.
(.*)$          ##Creating 3rd capturing group which has everything till end of value.
```